# values updated by a thread of different class not reflecting in an another class in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have edited my question and made it very simple.
First there are two classes on a same file
HashMapClass: which creates instance of ConccurentHashMap
and 
NewThread: which updates the hashMap

```
public class HashMapClass {

public static volatile ConcurrentHashMap serverMap = new ConcurrentHashMap();

public static void main(String args[]) {

    NewThread nt = new NewThread();
    nt.start();
}
}

class NewThread extends Thread {

@Override
public void run() {
    HashMapClass.serverMap.put("Ishan", new Integer(3));

System.out.println("Hash map is empty or not " + HashMapClass.serverMap.isEmpty());
  try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    }
}
```

Now here it shows that the hashMap is not empty but if i try to access it from other class New Class it shows empty

```
public class NewClass {

public static void main(String s[]) {
    System.out.println("Hash map is empty or not " + HashMapClass.serverMap.isEmpty());
    Set setMap = HashMapClass.serverMap.entrySet();
    Iterator i = setMap.iterator();
    for (int f = 0; i.hasNext(); ++f) {
        Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry) i.next();
        System.out.println("key is" + me.getKey() + "value is :" + me.getValue());
    }
}
```

}

this class is never updated with the data.
I hope this is easy to understand now.

Comment: [The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) precises that HashMap isn't thread safe. Read the advice. Don't share it between threads. A fast fix is to use a [Hashtable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html).

Comment: You can't get synchronization to work right by trial and error, sprinkling 'volatile' and 'synchronized' around your code like salt on a steak. You have to *design* it right. There is no other way.

Comment: Please look at the code one more time.Copy it and try to run it you will know the problem. I made it simple.

Comment: @dystroy please look at the question again. I have made it simple enough.

Answer (score 5):

HashMap is not thread safe so you need to introduce some form of synchronization if you need to share a HashMap accross threads.

Alternatively, and more simply, use a [ConcurrentHashMap which is thread safe](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

As a side not, you would probably benefit from reading the [Java tutorial on concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/), especially the part on [Memory consistency errors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html).

**EDIT**

Following your comment, see a simple example that, I think, isolates your issue - the output on my machine is:

> Hash map empty in main (1st attempt)? true
>   Hash map empty in run? false
>   Hash map empty in main (2nd attempt)? false

```
public class Test {

    public static ConcurrentMap serverMap = new ConcurrentHashMap();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        NewThread nt = new NewThread();
        nt.start();
        System.out.println("Hash map empty in main (1st attempt)? " + serverMap.isEmpty());
        Thread.sleep(200);
        System.out.println("Hash map empty in main (2nd attempt)? " + serverMap.isEmpty());
    }

    static class NewThread extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            serverMap.put("Ishan", new Integer(3));

            System.out.println("Hash map empty in run? " + serverMap.isEmpty());
        }
    }
}
```

**2ND EDIT**

You can apply the same logic from another class - just make sure you call NewThread.start and wait enough (or just call NewThread.run directly so that it is run in the same thread and you don't have to wait):

```
public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String s[]) throws InterruptedException {
        new Test.NewThread().start();
        System.out.println("Hash map is empty or not (1): " + Test.serverMap.isEmpty());
        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println("Hash map is empty or not (2): " + Test.serverMap.isEmpty());
        Set setMap = Test.serverMap.entrySet();
        Iterator i = setMap.iterator();
        for (int f = 0; i.hasNext(); ++f) {
            Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry) i.next();
            System.out.println("key is" + me.getKey() + "value is :" + me.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried ConcurrentHashMap but it didnt solve my problem. I also created a new class so that i can be sure that no other code is interrupting  but to no avail

Comment: @ishankalia I suggest you edit your question and post a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem, in other words a Test class with a main that prints something that shows what's wrong.

Comment: I have made the question simple as you have asked. please help me over this.

Comment: @ishankalia See my edited answer with an even more simple example (no need to make the concurrentmap volatile: it is already thread safe). Let me know if that helps you.

Comment: @ishankalia Also, if I run the main in your second class, hashmap is obviously empty as you don't call your newThread. Assuming I add a call to newThread.start() in the first line, your map will still very likley be empty at the next line, because the other thread has not had time to populate it yet.

Comment: but I want to access this map from other class NewClass which i have also written. I am running HashMapClass (which in your class is Test class) before running NewClass but it always show HashMap empty.

Comment: What i mean is that the problem arises only when you try to access the map from some other class which in my case is NewClass.

Comment: @ishankalia I'm not sure I understand. You first run HashMapClass.main, then you run NewClass.main?

Comment: you have made NewThread class an Inner class of Test but they must be separate classes other that that NewClass dont have to run the thread from there. i used the sleep() to stop program from exiting while other program works

Comment: Where the class is located does not make any difference. It is a different class

Comment: Do you first run HashMapClass.main, then you run NewClass.main?

Comment: See my comment below the other answer.

Comment: thank you friend. you are right. i think it is very basic thing that i didnt know and i feel terrible about that but thank you now i can easily sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

HashMap needs to be handled on its synchronization part, as its lacking thread safety

**ConcurrentHashMap** is better at concurrency, ConcurrentHashMap will not lock the Map while one is reading , neither will it lock the entire Map when writing to it. It gonna lock the part of the Map that is being written at present.

But its important to note that ConcurrentHashMap will not throw ConcurrentModificationException, if the ConcurrentHashMap is changed during its iteration.

**Edited Code:**

The problem was the HashMapClass and NewClass execution, when JVM has shutdown, after HashMapClass has completed its execution, how can we run NewClass class and try to retrieve the value which is stored in the ConcurrentHashMap, which is stored on the Heap, which is all lost as soon as jvm teminates. And yes as ConcurrentHashMap is marked static the value is stored in Memory-Area of the heap

```
public class HashMapClass {

public static  ConcurrentHashMap<String,Integer> serverMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,Integer>();

public static void main(String args[]) {

    NewThread nt = new NewThread();
    nt.start();
    try {
        nt.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    new NewClass().go();

  }
}

class NewThread extends Thread {


@Override
public void run() {

    HashMapClass.serverMap.put("Ishan", 3);

    System.out.println("Hash map is empty or not " + HashMapClass.serverMap.isEmpty());



    }
}

 class NewClass {

public void go() {
    System.out.println("Hash map is empty or not " + HashMapClass.serverMap.isEmpty());
    for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> m : HashMapClass.serverMap.entrySet()){

       System.out.println(m.getKey()+" "+m.getValue());
  }

}
}
```

Comment: I tried ConcurrentHashMap but it didnt solve my problem. I also created a new class so that i can be sure that no other code is interrupting but to no avail

Comment: Try using the generic HashMap or generic ConcurrentHashMap instead of non-generic

Comment: please look at the problem once again. I have made it simple you can paste and run the code now of both the files.

Comment: yes you are right sorry for that I understand your point. but i cant call the NewClass from HashMapClass in my program. I used sleep() to stop program from exiting while I run the NewClass.main() but it works the same. please try this prg this way dont call the NewClass object from the HashMapClass.

Comment: @ishankalia when you run the 2 main methods separately they run in different processes and there is no way they can access the same data without external communication (sockets for example) even if they run at the same time!!!

Comment: @assylias thank you friend. you are right. i think it is very basic thing that i didnt know and i feel terrible about that but thank you now i can easily sort it out.

Comment: @ Kumar Vivek Mitra thanks kumar for your post too. it helped. I am writing a chat application so may be I need for that in future as I have seen you have done a lot in networking. 
dhanyawad